# htaccess not recognized in vagrant VM / PuPHPet

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, centos, vagrant, puphpet

I'm in the process of setting up my first puphpet / vagrant box and all is well except that I can't get my site's .htaccess to be recognized. I installed CentOS with apache2 and MySQL and I'm running a rewrite to remove .php extensions:

```
# Redirect to remove .php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

However I keep getting page not found errors when I browse to, for example, site.com/login but I hit the page at site.com/login.php. I read a few threads here about changing /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and /etc/httpd/conf.d/10-default_vhost_80.conf to AllowOverride All, which I did, but had no luck after restarting httpd. Here's my config.yaml:

```
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/centos65-x64
        box_url: puphpet/centos65-x64
        hostname: null
        memory: '1024'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: vmware_fusion
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.10.200
            forwarded_port: {  }
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
                setextradata:
                    VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root: 1
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            ljjVKPIgQuXE:
                source: '/Users/Sean/Documents/Websites/RE Lynx'
                target: /var/www/relynx
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    auto: 'false'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        asawJQkN36Oa:
            servername: relynx.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.relynx.dev
            docroot: /var/www/relynx
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    vhosts:
        AYbF7pKHAyh0:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            location: \.php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '55'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: America/Chicago
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: '9000'
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        IpeE5TzgGzXe:
            version: ''
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    root_password: 'something'
    adminer: '1'
    databases:
        RuNUheO1cH27:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: rladmin_rladmin
            host: localhost
            user: rladmin_rladmin
            password: 'somethingelse'
            sql_file: /var/www/relynx/sql/rladmin_rladmin.sql
        8UkJkd4eF2TR:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: rladmin_rlhpsi
            host: localhost
            user: rladmin_rlhpsi
            password: 'somethingelseentirely'
            sql_file: /var/www/relynx/sql/rladmin_rlhpsi.sql
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        java_install: true
        autoupgrade: true
```

As an aside, I also tried this with Ubuntu 14 and got the same problem -- though at least in Ubuntu I could see that the vhost had AllowOveride All set, which I couldn't find in CentOS.  However, it appears to do no good either as my site's .htaccess file is not recognized in Ubuntu either.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue today.  From my debugging, I found that there is an issue with RewriteRules containing `.php` extension.  I got it working by switching to `mod_php` as it appears to be an issue with the implementation of PHP-FPM.

For more information on what I found and to see if you are having the same issue, please check out this issue: https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/1051

Note that switching to `mod_php` is a temporary solution until a better solution can be found.

Comment: How to switch to mod_php ? I've added mod_php: '1' in config.yaml, but it seems that doesn't work.